# How to add UTF-8 support to my hard disk in fstab?

Tags: fstab, utf-8

I use Ubuntu (Spanish language). Sometimes I get this error when I use special characters (codification error) so I read that if I edit a file of my hard disk by using `gedit /etc/fstab` and adding *utf8* I can fix it....

I had this line:

```
UUID=bfb5b95e-bf68-464a-8abf-d6027b039fa4 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

I adeed *utf8* like this:

```
UUID=bfb5b95e-bf68-464a-8abf-d6027b039fa4 / ext4 errors=remount-ro,iocharset=utf8 0 1
```

But I messed my Ubuntu and I can't log in now to my Ubuntu so im using live session... so I'll have to remove that code in order to be able to use my Ubuntu again. Can someone tell me how that line should look like?

Answer (score 4):

With ext4 (or ext3/2) you don't have to specify character set for filesystem. It does not care, as long as you are not using unescaped control characters in filenames.

Your system locale is more important thing. Try `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and select appropriate UTF-8 locale. Also, if you are using virtual terminal, make sure you have UTF-8 enabled (for example in GNOME Terminal: Terminal->Set Character Encoding).