# Issue on mounting partition

Tags: mount, vmware, fstab, tomcat, utf-8

So, I just got some issue on a Ubuntu 12.04.2 VM.

At boot, I wasn't able to mount my /data2 partition.

DMESG:

```
[    4.319405] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "utf8" or missing value
[244298.358642] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "utf8" or missing value
```

FSTAB:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/sda1       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sda5       none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
/dev/sdb1   /data2      ext4    rw,user,exec,utf8   0   0
```

PARTED:

```
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 22.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  11.3GB  11.3GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      11.3GB  22.5GB  11.3GB  extended
 5      11.3GB  22.5GB  11.3GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.2GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  32.2GB  32.2GB  primary  ext4
```

I solved it by removing that option from fstab, but I want to know if removing that option from fstab is harmless or not ?

That server is hosting tomcat instance.

Thx for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/28672/62612). Removing that option from the `/data2` partition should be fine. Especially since the option is unrecognized anyway.